# How to change default TokenIntrospectionProvider in KeyCloak

Tags: java, keycloak

When I call introspect endpoint, session's `lastAccess` does not get update. So I've created a custom `TokenIntrospectionProvider` and I am updating session's `lastAccess` using `setLastSessionRefresh`. After installing my custom provider, I can see provider name in admin UI but it does not work and token introspection is going through default provider.

I wanna change default `TokenIntrospectionProvider` and use my own class. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that you should pass the `token_type_hint` parameter with the name of `TokenIntrospectionProvider` to the `introspect` endpoint.

Example:

```
token = eyJhbG...XJsclg`
token_type_hint = arsi-token-introspection-provider
```